# Return text from URL ID

Tags: php

Recently I've been working on a little side project, aimed at being a wallpaper site. It'll mainly consist of my own photos, but I may implement some kind of upload system for other users to submit their own.

Essentially, I can make a page that takes an ID from the URL, e.g., `284` from `/wallpaper?id=284`. I can easily pop a .jpg after it and make a different image load depending on the ID. The annoying thing is, I'd like to also have a title/description accompany the photos, and I don't want to also have a title attribute in the URL at it would be easy to tamper with, even if not doing any damage.

I'm guessing this is to do with PHP tables (judging by the name and the sudden realisation that not much would be possible without something like it), which I can use as I'm currently running on a local WAMP server. I should also be able to when and if I upload this to an online server.

I'm basically asking how I can create some kind of document or table containing information that can be retrieved using some kind of ID.

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to use some kind of database [tag:mysql], [tag:mssql]... to link images to their details (title, description etc).

Comment: @DavidThomas I have access to MySQL database software, and have set up a table in phpMyAdmin, but I'm unsure of where to go next. I've added four entries, but how do I retrieve the information?

Comment: Start here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php